# Triggering event when anchor element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a list like this:

```
<ul class="titles clearfix">

 <li class="opened">Billing Address</li>
 <li class="">Shipping Address</li>
 <li class="">Review Order</li>

</ul>
```

And a button:

```
<a href="#">Next</a>
```

**How it's working:**

The first list item is opened by default (it has a class of "opened") and if I click on "Shipping address" (only if I click) the class "opened" it's applied to the "Shipping address".

What I want to do is, when I click on next to open "Shipping address" and If I click again to open "Review Order".

Basically, what I need to do is when "next" is clicked to force clicking "Shipping address" for example.

How can I do this?

Comment: You don't need to trigger an event. Just listen to the `click` events of your "button" and move the `opened` class in your handler. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` to set the class as needed, and `next()` to get the following `li` element. Try this:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    $('li.opened').removeClass('opened').next().addClass('opened');
});
```

If required, you would need to implement some logic to prevent the user going past the third `li` element.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0ocq9rep/)

Comment: Something strange is happening in my case, If I click on "next" button I get "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"

Comment: You need to include `jquery.js` in the page.

Comment: Working now, finally! Thank you!

Comment: Quick question: How can I remove the "next" button when the last element is opened and add it back if it's not?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var i = 2 ;
var len = $("ul li").length;

$('a').on('click', function(){    
    $("ul li.opened").removeClass('opened');
    $("ul li:nth-child("+ i +")").addClass('opened');
console.log(i, len);
    
    if (i == len) {
        i = 1;
    }else{
        i++;
    }
    
});
```

```css
.opened{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="titles clearfix">

 <li class="opened">Billing Address</li>
 <li class="">Shipping Address</li>
 <li class="">Review Order</li>

</ul>

<a href="#">Next</a>
```